# PDO fetch friends

Tags: php, pdo

I and new to PDO and I am trying to fetch the users that are already my friend but for some reason it does not fetch or tells me that they are already my friends. If I include COUNT('username') when they are not and if I delete COUNT tells me to send friend request to the users that are already my friends. Could someone point my problem. I know its in the check_frnd_query and the way I am trying to fetch the user. Thanks

```
Database 'frnds'Table

id = int
user_one = varchar 255
user_two = varchar 255
```

In friends table I have my username as user_one and user_two is my friend's username.

```
$check_frnd_query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT COUNT('username') FROM `frnds` WHERE ('user_one'='$my_id' AND 'user_two'='$userone') OR ('user_one'='$userone' AND 'user_two'='$my_id')");

$check_frnd_query->bindValue(':user_one', $user_one, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$check_frnd_query->bindValue(':user_two', $user_two, PDO::PARAM_STR);

try{

      $check_frnd_query->execute();

      $rows = $check_frnd_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      if(!empty($rows)){

         echo 'Already Friends';

      }else{
         echo 'Send Request Button!';
      }

}
```

Comment: please read and learn basic tutorials before asking questions. there are some eye screeching flaws in your first query, and binded values are not even close to matching the quey

Answer (score 0):

You are not binding the parameters correctly. It should be be :user_one instead of $my_id and :user_two instead of $userone in the mysql query. So your query becomes:

```
$check_frnd_query = $this->db->prepare("
  SELECT COUNT('username')
  FROM `frnds`
  WHERE ('user_one'=:user_one AND 'user_two'=:user_two) OR
    ('user_one'=:user_two AND 'user_two'=:user_one)");
```

Comment: Those quotes around user_one and user_two won't help if you want to check database fields.